# Transient with Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2, moshi

Trying to display a really poorly designed JSON and running into issues. The array inside the array is not needed for my purposes so I am trying to exclude it from my response in hope it will stop throwing the errors.

Ugly JSON

```
{
    "id": "65",
    "name": "Switch - Kitchen",
    "label": "Switch - Kitchen",
    "attributes": [
        {
            "name": "switch",
            "currentValue": "off",
            "dataType": "ENUM",
            "values": [
                "on",
                "off"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "capabilities": [
        "Switch",
        {
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "name": "switch",
                    "dataType": null
                }
            ]
        },
        "Configuration",
        "Refresh",
        "Actuator"
    ],
    "commands": [
        "configure",
        "flash",
        "off",
        "on",
        "refresh",
        "refresh"
    ]
}
```

DeviceDetails Class

```
    @Transient val attributes: List<Attribute>,
    val capabilities: List<String>,
    val commands: List<String>,
    val id: String,
    val label: String,
    val name: String
)
```

Attribute Class (not needed)

```
data class Attribute(
    val currentValue: String,
    val dataType: String,
    val name: String,
    val values: List<String>
)
```

Details API

```
interface DeviceDetailsAPI {
    @GET("devices/65")
    fun getAllDetails(@Query("access_token") access_token: String): Observable<List<DeviceDetails>>
}
```

API Call

```
object DeviceDetailsWebAccess {
    val deviceDetailsApi: DeviceDetailsAPIClient by lazy {
        Log.d("DeviceDetailsWebAccess", "Creating details retrofit client")
        //Debugging URL//
        val interceptor : HttpLoggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
            this.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY }
        val client : OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder().apply {
            this.addInterceptor(interceptor)}.build()
        //Debugging URL//
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/apps/api/109/")
            // Moshi maps JSON to classes
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
            // The call adapter handles threads
            .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
            .client(client)
            .build()

        // Create Retrofit client
        return@lazy retrofit.create(DeviceDetailsAPIClient::class.java)
    }
}
```

Adapter

```
class DeviceDetailsAdapter (var deviceDetails: List<DeviceDetails>, val clickListener: (DeviceDetails) -> Unit) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.device_detail, parent, false)
        return PartViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = deviceDetails.size

    class PartViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        fun bind(device: DeviceList) {
            itemView.device_item_name.text = device.name
            itemView.device_item_id.text = device.id
            itemView.device_item_label.text = device.label
        }
    }
}
```

Main Activity

```
class MainActivity2 : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val tag : String = MainActivity2::class.java.simpleName
    private lateinit var adapterDetails: DeviceDetailsAdapter
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        rv_devices.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        rv_devices.hasFixedSize()
        adapterDetails = DeviceDetailsAdapter(listOf()) { deviceDetails: DeviceDetails -> deviceDetails }
        rv_devices.adapter = adapterDetails
        loadDeviceDetails()
    }

        private fun loadDeviceDetails() {
            GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                try {
                    val webResponseDetails = DeviceDetailsWebAccess.deviceDetailsApi.getDevicesDetailsAsync(access_token = "xxxxxxxx").await()
                    if (webResponseDetails.isSuccessful) {
                        val deviceDetails: List<DeviceDetails>? = webResponseDetails.body()
                        //Log.d(tag, deviceDetails?.toString())
                        //adapterDetails.deviceDetails = deviceDetails ?: listOf()
                        adapterDetails.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    } else {
                        Log.e(tag, "Error ${webResponseDetails.code()}")
                        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity2, "Error ${webResponseDetails.code()}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    Log.e(tag, "Exception " + e.printStackTrace())
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity2, "Exception ${e.message}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am getting the following error:

```
com.squareup.moshi.JsonDataException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at path $
```

It does not point to where the issue is which I find odd? I am tracing the JSON call and it shows the "Attribute" array is still being parsed. What am I doing wrong? Why is Transient not working? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Could you confirm the root json is an array which matches the List<DeviceDetails> ?

Comment: Added more code for more context

Answer (score 2):

The error says the problem exists at `path $`, which is the root.

Your problem is that you're saying the JSON is a `List<DeviceDetails>`, but it seems to actually just be a single `DeviceDetails`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Kiskae answered, the class expects a list of DeviceDetails and the current JSON would be a DeviceDetails object.

Typically a List in the model class corresponds to array syntax in JSON of `[ {object 1}, {object 2} ]`

Your root JSON is an object - To change it so you can parse the JSON you need to either return an array in the JSON which would mean returning DeviceDetails in the place of object 1 above which maps to your `Observable<List<DeviceDetails>>` or change the get details api call so it parses a DeviceDetails object `Observable<DeviceDetails>`

The JSON you have posted would mean changing the api to expect `Observable<DeviceDetails>`

Once you've resolved this you will need to model the `Capabilities` object in your DeviceDetails class as the JSON is not an array of String. It's an array of an unmodelled object. (String, Attributes Wrapper, String, String)

Comment: Add a opening curly brace where?

Comment: Before the start of the json, so change:

 `"id": "65",` to  `{  "id": "65",`

Comment: Ok, see my updated answer on JSON array and object differences

Comment: How do I change it from an object to a array?

Comment: I've added how this is done in my answer. Why do you need to return an array? This would mean parsing multiple DeviceDetails. Your api call with name getDeviceDetails suggests you only need to return 1 DeviceDetails object.

Comment: @user1722885 - Was the comment and updated answer any help?

Comment: Sorry I am very new to this and not sure how to do this. If I try and return the observable in an array (done it before) it errors on the attributes class. So my thought was to use moshi and transient attributes since I dont need that section anyway. So why does it error if I return just the one object?

Comment: I think this is because you have a List<DeviceDetails> in the getAllDetails. It will look for a `[` as the first character in the JSON response as its trying to deserialise into you List<DeviceDetails>  You currently have `{` as the first character which denotes start of JSON Object and therefore only DeviceDetails. Change to Observable<DeviceDetails> and see if that helps

Comment: You are welcome! Could you accept my answer please?